# Local storage data not saving on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am creating a settings portion on a website. I want the features chosen to be "saved" and kept when the page refreshes. I attempted this but it seems to just reset the form when I refresh the page. Another issue is when I click on the cancel button, the toggle buttons reset but the dropdown comes back blank instead of going back to the placeholder "select timezone". The issue most likely lies in my javascript code below. It's also throwing an error in stack overflow but works properly on my website (minus the issues described above). Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```js
//  ---------- TOGGLE BTN ----------
const toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
const labels = document.getElementsByClassName("labels");

for(let i=0; i < 2; i++) {
    labels[i].innerHTML = "OFF";
    toggle[i].addEventListener( "click", () => {
        if(labels[i].innerHTML == "OFF") {
            // console.log("button toggled");
            labels[i].classList.add("on");
            labels[i].innerHTML= "ON";
        } else {
            labels[i].classList.remove("on");
            labels[i].innerHTML = "OFF";
        }
    });
}

// ---------- LOCAL STORAGE DATA ----------

const save = document.getElementById("save");
const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");
const emailBtn = document.getElementById("togBtn");
const publicBtn = document.getElementById("togBtn2");
const zone = document.getElementById("timezone");

// emailBtn.value = data;
// publicBtn.value = data;
// zone.value = data;

const data = {
email: emailBtn.value,
privacy: publicBtn.value,
timezone: zone.value
}



var emailVal = localStorage.getItem("email");
var privacyVal = localStorage.getItem("privacy");
var zoneVal = localStorage.getItem("timezone");

save.addEventListener('click', () => {

    localStorage.setItem("email", emailBtn.value);
    localStorage.setItem("privacy", publicBtn.value);
    localStorage.setItem("timezone", zone.value);
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.clear();

    for(let i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        labels[i].innerHTML = "OFF";
        labels[i].classList.remove("on");
    }

    emailBtn.checked = false;
    publicBtn.checked =false;
    
    zone.value = 'Select Timezone';
});
```

```css
.settings {
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.settings h3 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.button1,
.button2 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}

label {
    flex-basis: 90%;
}

input {
    flex-basis: 10%;
}


.form-field {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    color: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
}

.settings-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
   
}

button {
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#save,
#cancel {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

#save {
    background-color: #7477BF;
    color: white;
}

#cancel {
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: white;
}

#timezone {
    margin-top:25px;
}

/* toggle button */


.toggle {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    
}

.toggle:after {
    content: '';
    width: 80px;
    height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(196, 195, 195, 0.55);
    border: 2px solid rgba(196, 195, 195, 0.55);
    
    border-radius: 18px;
    clear: both;
}

.toggle:before {
    content: '';
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    /* left: 0;
    top: -3px; */
    border: 2px solid rgba(196, 195, 195, 0.55);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.toggle:checked:before {
    left: 54px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}

.toggle:checked:after {
    background: #7477BF;
    
}

.toggle,
.toggle:before,
.toggle:after,
.toggle:checked:before,
.toggle:checked:after {
    transition: ease .4s;
    -webkit-transition: ease .4s;
    -moz-transition: ease .4s;
    -o-transition: ease .4s;
}

.labels {
    color: gray;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    transform: translate(-48px, -3px);
}

.on {
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-90px, -3px);
}
```

```html
<section class="settings" id="settings">
            <h3>Settings</h3>
        <!-- custom CSS toggle code-->
        <div class="button1">
            <label for="togBtn">Send Email Notfications </label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="togBtn">
            <span class="labels"></span>
        </div>
            <div class="button2">
                <label for="togBtn2">Set Profile to Public &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="togBtn2">
                <span class="labels"></span>
            </div> 
        
       <select class="form-field" id="timezone">
            <option disabled selected>Select a Timezone</option>
            <option>Eastern</option>
            <option>Western</option>
        <!-- more options -->
       </select>
       
       <div class="settings-button" >
           <button class="button-primary" id="save">Save</button>
           <button class="button-disabled" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
       </div>
       </section>
```

Comment: you have no control over the page refresh button as it is a browser feature that is soley under control of the user. Binding an eventListener to it will also not help as the script will not excute anymore as the page is refreshed. The only thing youc an do is to save the data to the lcoal storage the very moment changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

here a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/window-load-event-forked-8xx723).

The problems with your code were that you were using `emailBtn.value` and `publicBtn.value` instead of `emailBtn.checked` and `publicBtn.checked` (they are checkbox so in order to get the correct value you have to read che `checked` property) and you were not loading the saved values on document load (the function inside `window.addEventListener("load", ...)` in my example.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works to save the buttons the first time! but if you continue to unclick and save and then refresh, they come back clicked still with the label "OFF". The program seems to glitch like this after the first save. I added this loop in the window load event listener but it only solves half of the problem:

Comment: for(let i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (emailVal === "true") {
        labels[i].classList.add("on");
        labels[i].innerHTML = "ON";
        }  else if (emailVal === "false") {
        labels[i].classList.remove("on");
        labels[i].innerHTML = "OFF";
        }

        if (privacyVal === "true") {
        labels[i].classList.add("on");
        labels[i].innerHTML = "ON";
        } else if (privacyVal === "false") {
            labels[i].classList.remove("on");
            labels[i].innerHTML = "OFF";
            
         }
    }

Comment: @Tatyana I updated the example, take a look now.

Comment: I just clicked the link again and it didn't change on my end :(

Comment: I actually figured that part out! The only issue I have left is why the timezone value doesn't go back to the placeholder "Select Timezone' when clicking cancel. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Tatyana nice to have helped you.